# How do I count all the files recursively through directories

Tags: disk-usage, recursive, inode

I want to see how many files are in subdirectories to find out where all the inode usage is on the system. Kind of like I would do this for space usage

```
du -sh /*
```

which will give me the space used in the directories off of root, but in this case I want the number of files, not the size.

Comment: See also [recursively count all the files in a directory](http://superuser.com/questions/198817), [Count files in each directory?](http://superuser.com/questions/210356) at SU.

Comment: I think that "how many files are in subdirectories in there subdirectories" is a confusing construction.  If more clearly state what you want, you might get an answer that fits the bill.

Comment: @Steven feel free to rewrite it... I thought my example of `du -sh /*` made it pretty clear how I wanted the count to work. same thing, just count the files not the bytes.

Comment: As you mention inode usage, I don't understand whether you want to count the number of files or the number of used inodes. The two are different when hard links are present in the filesystem. Most, if not all, answers give the number of files. Don't use them on an Apple Time Machine backup disk.

Comment: @mouviciel this isn't being used on a backup disk, and yes I suppose they might be different, but in the environment I'm in there are very few hardlinks, technically I just need to get a feel for it. figure out where someone is burning out there inode quota.

Comment: @mouviciel of course feel free to suggest a way to get the actual inode count

Comment: `du` should provide a builtin feature for this.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat, `ncdu` does have a builtin feature for this, see answer below  :)

Comment: Actually I have since realized that `du` provides pretty much a solution built in.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read -r dir
do printf "%s:\t" "$dir"; find "$dir" -type f | wc -l; done
```

Thanks to Gilles and xenoterracide for safety/compatibility fixes.

The first part: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d` will return a list of all directories in the current working directory. 
(Warning: `-maxdepth` is a GNU extension
and might not be present in non-GNU versions of `find`.) 
This is piped to...

The second part: `while read -r dir; do`
(shown above as `while read -r dir`(newline)`do`) begins a `while` loop – as long as the pipe coming into the `while` is open (which is until the entire list of directories is sent), the `read` command will place the next line into the variable `dir`. Then it continues...

The third part: `printf "%s:\t" "$dir"` will print the string in `$dir`
(which is holding one of the directory names) followed by a colon and a tab
(but not a newline).

The fourth part: `find "$dir" -type f` makes a list of all the files
inside the directory whose name is held in `$dir`. This list is sent to...

The fifth part: `wc -l` counts the number of lines that are sent into its standard input.

The final part: `done` simply ends the `while` loop.

So we get a list of all the directories in the current directory. For each of those directories, we generate a list of all the files in it so that we can count them all using `wc -l`. The result will look like:

```
./dir1: 234
./dir2: 11
./dir3: 2199
...
```

Comment: Always use `read -r` as plain `read` treats backslashes specially. Then `echo -en "$dir:\t"` will again mangle backslashes; a simple fix is to use `printf '%s:\t' "$dir"` instead. Next, `$dir` should be `"$dir"` (**always use double quotes around variable substitutions**).

Comment: modified per @Giles suggestions `find -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read -r dir; do printf "%s:\t" "$dir"; find "$dir" | wc -l; done`

Comment: I'm adding `sort -n -r -k2` to the end of this, for lots of directories, so that I know where the most usage is

Comment: The fourth part: find "$dir" makes a list of all the files inside the directory name held in "$dir". You forgot to add `-type f` to make it list files: `find -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read -r dir; do printf "%s:\t" "$dir"; find "$dir" -type f | wc -l; done`

Comment: @krzysiek-boduch Thanks! I updated the answer.

Comment: where do I write the name of the root directory?

Comment: I'm not getting this to work on macOS Sierra 10.12.5. `illegal option -- m` in the `find` command. I changed it to `find . -maxdepth ...` and got it to work.

Comment: @xenoterracide you might have dirs with spaces, maybe better setting tab as delimiter `sort -rt $'\t' -k 2,2 -V`. Also `2>/dev/null` after wc pipe to get rid of permission errors.

Comment: Why do you count only files? Directories take inodes as well as [files](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/8a5c89bb5363f0e8eb0a5cad3d49db0c). And well, the directory itself also takes an inode, but that doesn't affect the result much. Anyways, the [other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/497252/29867) must be top-most and accepted.

Comment: On Mac OS, it also counts the .DS_Store inside each directory. You can exclude them with the `-type f ! -iname ".*"` find parameter. You could also want to exclude files starting by `~*`.

Answer (score 77):

Try `find . -type f | wc -l`, it will count of all the files in the current directory as well as all the files in subdirectories. Note that all directories will not be counted as files, only ordinary files do.

Comment: Just to be clear: Does it count files in the subdirectories of the subdirectories etc...?

Comment: @Kvothe Yes, recursively. :)

Answer (score 22):

Here's a compilation of some useful listing commands (re-hashed based on previous users code):

**List folders with file count:**

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort | while read -r dir; do n=$(find "$dir" -type f | wc -l); printf "%4d : %s\n" $n "$dir"; done
```

**List folders with non-zero file count:**

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort | while read -r dir; do n=$(find "$dir" -type f | wc -l); if [ $n -gt 0 ]; then printf "%4d : %s\n" $n "$dir"; fi; done
```

**List folders with sub-folder count:**

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort | while read -r dir; do n=$(find "$dir" -type d | wc -l); let n--; printf "%4d : %s\n" $n "$dir"; done
```

**List folders with non-zero sub-folder count:**

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort | while read -r dir; do n=$(find "$dir" -type d | wc -l); let n--; if [ $n -gt 0 ]; then printf "%4d : %s\n" $n "$dir"; fi; done
```

**List empty folders:**

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort | while read -r dir; do n=$(find "$dir" | wc -l); let n--; if [ $n -eq 0 ]; then printf "%4d : %s\n" $n "$dir"; fi; done
```

**List non-empty folders with content count:**

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort | while read -r dir; do n=$(find "$dir" | wc -l); let n--; if [ $n -gt 0 ]; then printf "%4d : %s\n" $n "$dir"; fi; done
```

Comment: And btw.. if you want to have the output of any of these list commands sorted by the item count .. pipe the command into a sort : "a-list-command" | sort -n

Comment: all those `if`'s could be easily replaced with `find [-not] -empty`

Comment: @DolphinDream thanks, sort -n is good

Answer (score 16):

Try:

```
find /path/to/start/at -type f -print | wc -l
```

as a starting point, or if you really only want to recurse through the subdirectories of a directory (and skip the files in that top level directory)

```
find `find /path/to/start/at -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print` -type f -print | wc -l
```

Comment: +1 for something | wc -l  ... word count is such a nice little tool

Comment: yeah but this only does 1 directory.... I'd like to get the count for all directories in a directory, and I don't want to run it seperately each time... of course I suppose I could use a loop... but I'm being lazy.

Comment: `find` works recursively through all sub directories by default. If you want it to work in multiple locations, you can specify all of them between `find` and `-type`.

Comment: that second one certainly doesn't work.... I tried it on /home . I got `698035 `. I should see about 6 numbers.

Comment: It works for me - are you sure you only have 6 files under `/home`?  I'd be 100% certain you don't.

Comment: @Cry I have maybe 6 directories... not 6 files

Answer (score 11):

## du --inodes

I'm not sure why no one (myself included) was aware of:

```
du --inodes
```

```
--inodes
      list inode usage information instead of block usage
```

I'm pretty sure this solves the OP's problem. I've started using it a lot to find out where all the junk in my huge drives is (and offload it to an older disk).

#### Further info

If you DON'T want to recurse (which can be useful in other situations), add

```
-S, --separate-dirs
```

Comment: a very nice option but not in all version of `du` :(

Comment: I'm curious, which OS is that? I'm able to get it for Ubuntu and Mac OS X

Comment: not in `freebsd` :(

Comment: I've never used BSD but did you try installing coreutils? I think that gives the GNU version of du. https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/coreutils/

Comment: I might at some point but right now I'll probably make due with other solutions

Answer (score 7):

If you have `ncdu` installed (a must-have when you want to do some cleanup), simply type `c` to "Toggle display of child item counts". And `C` to "Sort by items".

Comment: lol, this must be the top-most accepted answer :)

Comment: While useful this *does* also count sub-directories as items.

Answer (score 4):

The following solution counts the actual number of used inodes starting from current directory:

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 ls -id | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort -u | wc -l
```

To get the number of files of the same subset, use:

```
find . | wc -l
```

For solutions exploring only subdirectories, without taking into account files in current directory, you can refer to other answers.

Comment: Good idea taking hard links into account. Assuming GNU find, you don't need so many steps: `find -printf '%i\n' | sort -u | wc -l`. If you wanted to be portable, you'd need `find . -exec ls -id {} + | cut …` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
find -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'printf "%s\t%s\n" "$(find "{}" -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)" "{}"'
```

It should work fine unless filenames include newlines.

Comment: way too recursive... I only want to see the top level, where it totals everything underneath it. totaled... this ends up printing every directory.

Comment: @xenoterracide: Try adding `-maxdepth 1` immediately after the first `find`. If you want to include the number of subdirectories in your count, remove the `-type f` at the end (that should have really been `! -type d` anyway, so that all non-directory files would have been included).

Answer (score 2):

OS X 10.6 chokes on the command in the accepted answer, because it doesn't specify a path for `find`. Instead use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read -r dir; do printf "%s:\t" "$dir"; find "$dir" -type f | wc -l; done
```

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late to the party, but I believe this pure `bash` (or other shell which accept double star glob) solution could be much faster in some situations:

```
shopt -s globstar    # to enable ** glob in bash
for dir in */; do a=( "$dir"/**/* ); printf "%s\t%s\n" "$dir:" "${#a[*]}"; done
```

output:

```
d1/:    302
d2/:    24
d3/:    640
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this recursive function to list total files in a directory recursively, up to a certain depth (it counts files and directories from all depths, but show print total count up to the max_depth):

```
#!/bin/bash
# set -x

export max_depth="2"
export found_files="/tmp/found_files.txt"

function get_all_the_files()
{
    depth="$1";
    base_directory="$2";

    if [[ "$depth" -ge "$max_depth" ]];
    then
        return;
    fi

    find "$base_directory" -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read -r inner_directory
    do
        printf "%s\t%s\n" "$(find "$inner_directory" | wc -l)" "$inner_directory" | tee -a "$found_files";
        if [[ "w$(realpath "$base_directory")" != "w$(realpath "$inner_directory")" ]];
        then
            get_all_the_files "$(( depth + 1 ))" "$inner_directory";
        fi;
    done;
}

rm -f "$found_files"
get_all_the_files 0 /tmp/

printf '\nFinished searching files, sorting all:\n'
sort --version-sort "$found_files"
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the folder (directory) you want to count (`cd /my/dir`) you can do the following:

1. To count **all folders and files**:
   `find . | wc -l`
2. To count only **folders** (directories):
   `find . -type d | wc -l`
3. To count only **files**:
   `find . -type f | wc -l`

This way you are able to verify that: `folders (2) + files (3) = total (1)`

---

**Some explanation**:

- The command `find .` will print each of all the folders (directories) and files line by line.

  - The parameter: `-type d` says to print only `d`irectories (folders)
  - The parameter: `-type f` says to print only `f`iles.
- The command `wc -l` should mean something like: `word count` with the parameter: `lines`.