# sort output by column

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sort

I'd like to take this command `find -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read -r dir; do printf "%s:\t" "$dir"; find "$dir" | wc -l; done` ( [from here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4105/29) ). which has an output of basically

```
./kennel:       11062
./shadow:       15449
./ccc:  9765
./journeyo:     14200
./norths:       10710
```

and sort it by the numbers largest to smallest. but I'm not sure how to make `sort`, or whatever operate on a different column.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Pipe the lines through `sort -n -r -k2`.
Edited to sort from largest to smallest.

Comment: Tried it and works flawlessly

Answer (score 4):

One option is to flip the columns:

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read -r dir; do printf "%d\t%s\n" "`find "$dir" | wc -l`" "$dir"; done
```

Then you get output like this:

```
17  .
1   ./acroread_1000_1002
1   ./.ICE-unix
2   ./.X11-unix
1   ./orbit-mrozekma
2   ./ns.mrozekma.:0
```

You can pipe that through `sort -nr` to sort it the way you want. You can even pipe the sorted result through something like `awk -F'\t' '{print $2 "\t" $1}'` to flip the columns back if you need them in that order