# Get the number of inode in a tree

Tags: inode

How can I get the number of inodes used by files in a given directory tree?
Important: including hidden directories under it, like `.git`

Comment: @ptman: thanks, but my problem is mostly about the "Important" warning...

Comment: And why would `find .` exclude those?

Comment: Woops, turns out it does not, you're right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As found on [How do I count all the files recursively through directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4105/how-do-i-count-all-the-files-recursively-through-directories)

```
find . -printf '%i\n' | sort -u | wc -l
```

Or if you don't have GNU find and need a portable version:

```
find . -exec ls -id '{}' \; | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u | wc -l
```

Comment: solaris wont like that because of the multiple spaces before the inode number, you also need to uniquely sort before counting lines, as im sure you know. `find . -exec ls -id {} \; |awk '{print $1}' | sort -u | wc -l`

Comment: @Sirch you are of course correct. Fixed.