# Counting files in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, files

I'd like to get a count of all files in a directory and its subdirectories but I don't want it to count .zip files. So I think something like this:

```
find . -iname "*.zip" -type f 2> /dev/null | wc -l
```

Except backwards - that would only return .zip files and I want to only count the other files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a count of files in a directory using the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/how-can-i-get-a-count-of-files-in-a-directory-using-the-command-line)

Comment: Or https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4105/377345

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
LC_ALL=C find .//. ! -iname '*.zip' -type f 2> /dev/null |
  LC_ALL=C grep -c //
```

To count the regular files whose name doesn't end in `.zip`.

A few notes:

- to negate a test in `find` expressions, just prepend `!` to it. Some `find` implementations also support `-not` for that, though that's not standard nor portable.
- you want to disable localisation for `find` (with `LC_ALL=C`) to find file names which end with `.zip` even if the filenames don't constitutes valid text in the user's locale. Also the uppercase character for `i` depends on the locale (in some it's `I`, in others it's `İ`). In the C locale, it's `I`. Using  `-name '*.[zZ][iI][pP]'` would make it standard and more deterministic.
- file paths can be made of several lines, using `wc -l` to count them doesn't make sense. Here, we use `find .//.` so to have something (`//`) unique to look for in each file path, which we're counting with `grep -c`. With GNU tools, you can also use `find ... -print0 | sed -z '$='` though that would not give any output if there was 0 files found. `find ... -print0 | tr -cd '\0' | wc -c` would be better (but could have whitespace around the number). See also `find ... -print0 | gawk -v 'RS=\0' 'END{print NR}'`. Or with GNU `find`: `find ... -printf . | wc -c`.